# I am trying to create a regex for a list of accepted symbols and character string

Tags: regex

I am building a test function that should only accept the following:

`-`
`*`
`+`
`.`
`,`
`$`
`9`
`Z`
`V`
`B`
`CR` - only once not with `DB`
`DB` - only once not with `CR`

I have gotten the first few to work like so: `new RegExp(/^([\-\*+.,$9ZVB]|CR|DB)*$/gm)`, but I annot get the regex to only allow the CR or DB to appear only once either at beginning or end of the string.  Any suggestions?

Test at https://regex101.com/r/1qT86R/2

Comment: If you are using [regex101](https://regex101.com/), why don't you include a link to a regex? That would clarify which regex engine you are using and what text you are using to test. By the way, CR is carriage return, but what is DB?

Comment: I work in financial and CR is credit and DB is debit

Comment: "I am having trouble" is not a specific problem description. Please edit your post to clarify that and ask a more specific question

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^(?:(?=[-*+.,$9ZVB]*DB[-*+.,$9ZVB]*$)(?!.*CR)|(?=[-*+.,$9ZVB]*CR[-*+.,$9ZVB]*$)(?!.*DB))([-*+.,$9ZVB]|CR|DB)+$`  https://regex101.com/r/Uu0Rvy/1

Comment: Are `CR` & `DB` **allways** at the end of the string? If yes then `^[-*+.,$9ZVB]+(?:CR|DB)$` does the job.

Comment: CR &DB are optional, they may not be included in the string at all.  if they are included, they would only be at the beginning or end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression:

```regex
^(CR|DB)[-*+.,$9ZVB]+$|^[-*+.,$9ZVB]+(CR|DB)$
```

or

```regex
^((CR|DB)[-*+.,$9ZVB]+|[-*+.,$9ZVB]+(CR|DB))$
```

You can test it here: https://regexr.com/58tf1

Comment: Is there a way to ensure that for CR/DB would only 1 occurrence of either CR or DB?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using javascript.

You can use the regex:

```
^(?:(?:CR|DB)[-*+.,$9ZVB]+|[-*+.,$9ZVB]+(?:CR|DB))$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/7yDJG0/2)

```js
var test = [
    '$---,---,--9.99BCR',
    '$---,---,--9.99BDB',
    'CR$---,---,--9.99B',
    'DB$---,---,--9.99B',
    'CR$---,---,--9.99BCR',
    'CR$---,---,--9.99BDB',
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a+' : '+/^(?:(?:CR|DB)[-*+.,$9ZVB]+|[-*+.,$9ZVB]+(?:CR|DB))$/.test(a);
}));
```

Comment: The expression is incorrect, it not works, for example, for `CR9` string.